# Can't see the buttons on my toolbar (WPF, xaml)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

As you can read in the title, I can't see the buttons if I run the the program. I can only see them if my courser is on the code.

```
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="nenu" Margin="0,0,-891,0">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Start"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Stop"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Safe"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Bearbeiten">
                <MenuItem Header="_Add filter"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Delete filter"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="30">
            <Button><Image x:Name="StartBttn" Source="layouts\start.png"/></Button>
            <Button><Image x:Name="StopBttn" Source="layouts\stop.png"/></Button>
            <Button><Image x:Name="SafeBttn" Source="layouts\save.png"/></Button>
            <Button><Image x:Name="AddBttn" Source="layouts\add.png"/></Button>
            <Button><Image x:Name="DeleteBttn" Source="layouts\delete.png"/></Button>
        </ToolBar>
    </DockPanel>
```

The icons are 20x20 pixel. I searched in the internet and tried some things out but nothing worked. Hope you guys can see what I can't.

Comment: -891? Is that right?

Comment: yes, -891 if the value would be positiv, I can't see the menu anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I solved the problem

I had to set the propertie of the button "Stretch" to none. Now I can see the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Use Right Slash

```
    <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="30">
        <Button><Image x:Name="StartBttn" Source="layouts/start.png"/></Button>
        <Button><Image x:Name="StopBttn" Source="layouts/stop.png"/></Button>
        <Button><Image x:Name="SafeBttn" Source="layouts/save.png"/></Button>
        <Button><Image x:Name="AddBttn" Source="layouts/add.png"/></Button>
        <Button><Image x:Name="DeleteBttn" Source="layouts/delete.png"/></Button>
    </ToolBar>
```

Comment: Check Build Action Resource for each .png file

Comment: Select the file in Solution Explorer, right click and select Properties, In properties window you can see it.

Comment: It only shows me the name of the folder (using VS 2013)

Comment: Select start.png in Solution Explorer, right click and select Properties, In properties window you can see it.

Comment: ok, I got it ... but it only shows userdefind tool, file name and the path of the file